# How to enable BDS2006's C++ WARN & TRACE macros

Tags: c++, debugging, c++builder, trace

I am trying to find out how to enable (& use) Borland's WARN & TRACE macros.

My starting point was this link:
http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol2/9809/Debugging_with_diagnostic_macros.htm?PHPSESSID=37bf58851bfeb5c199d1af31d7b2e7ff

However, that appears to be for BCB5, and not the 2006 Borland Developer Studio.

- I've set the two defines (__WARN & __TRACE)
- I've included the .h file ()
- I've added some macros, and everything compiles & links fine.

But when I run the application (in DEBUG mode), no debug output file is created.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you have a look at the checks.h header to see if it still uses the same macros to enable the TRACE macro?

Comment: Yes, checks.h has the same two macros defined. There is something in there to do with DiagGroups, but I'm not sure if that is relevant or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was investigating this debug TRACE feature too since I use Borland's toolchain. A couple things I noted while I was figure this out.

- Make sure `__TRACE` and `__WARN` are define before `#include <checks.h>`.
  You can also remove the #define __TRACE and __WARN from the translation unit and instead pass it to bcc32 using the -D *macroname* option during compilation.
- _GetDiagGroupDef is unresolved for BDS2006. It seems the compiler toolchain that comes with BDS2006 and later seems to be missing some function and class implementation that checks.h uses -- in particular _GetDiagGroupDef. I get unresolved references from the linker when compiling a test sample that uses checks.h. This doesn't happen when I use BCB 5.5.1 btw. Using grep/findstr it appears checks.cpp is compiled into the runtime library of BCB5.5.1 but it's missing from BDS2006 toolchain. I'm surprised you didn't run into the same problem, perhaps I didn't install some components. I found a copy of checks.cpp from an older borland toolchain [here](http://imach.uran.ru/p/SOFTWARE/temp/CBuilder5/Source/RTL/source/misc/checks.cpp). Compiling and linking that should fix the unresolved errors.
- The tutorial says that the outdbg1.txt is a temporary file and it only shows up in the borland IDE -- for that file to actually exist you must save it. This suggest to me that their TRACE/WARN Macros doesn't actually output a debug file. It's probably outputting the debug info to a stderr stream.

If that's really the case then redirecting the stderr stream to a file should give what you're looking for. Compile your sample program, then run it with something like this:

```
myprogram.exe 2> outdbg1.txt
```

All in all, you'll probably want to find alternative tools to aid you in the debugging process. Unfortunately, the TRACE & WARN macros provided here are poorly documented and for later versions of borland/embarcadero's toolchain it doesn't even work properly because the rtl doesn't have the needed functions/classes compiled into it. As such, the following is worth investigating:

1. OutputDebugString API. This has the advantage that any monitor program that uses this API can receive debug message strings from your program that's being debugged.
2. xUnit Testing Framework. [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) is worth checking out.
3. and of course your standard integrated IDE debugger :P